# Xamarin.forms, Android deployment issue. App is failing to Deploy on Emulators and physical devices

Tags: android, forms, xamarin

UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
[MonoDroid] Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider androidx.core.content.FileProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.core.content.FileProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~pZAuPuPF-r125lb9dLdbVw==/com.cfj.TrialwatchApp-RevQziFDZKEkLVVkaCkhEg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~pZAuPuPF-r125lb9dLdbVw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you added below code under AndroidManifest.xml under Android Properties?

Please Add Below Code under Application Tag.

```
<provider android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="yourpackagename.fileprovider" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:exported="false">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
</provider>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to update your [xamarin forms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms/) and [Xamarin.Essentials](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Essentials/) nuget to the latest ones and try again.

If the problem persist, you can recheck if you have added the following code under  `Application`  tag as Krunal Bagadia said.

```
<provider android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
</provider>
```

Comment: Actually i was able to fixed this issue. Thanks for help